# Struts2 Interceptor based on specific URl Patterns

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

I want to use a struts2 interceptor for all actions which start with the specific name:

Say I want to intercept all actions which start with **Module**. Is there any way I can configure an interceptor something like the Spring **AOP** does e.g: `com.acme.web.actions.Module*`

I can't use AOP because it breaks all page params (As I guess there is no way the params interceptor is invoked there).

is this possible?

Comment: IMO whoever downvoted it was wrong. Although the information is not extensive, it was consise and perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Struts you can define different interceptor stacks and [apply different stacks to different actions](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptor-configuration.html).

So in your situation you can define a different stack like this:

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="myInterceptor" class="com.company.security.MyInterceptor"/>
  <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="myInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

And, using [wildcard mappings](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html), the configuration bellow is essentially "map all actions named ModuleSomething to a class  com.acme.web.actions.ModuleSometing, and apply myStack of interceptors to it:

```
<action name="Module*" class="com.acme.web.actions.Module{1}">
  <result>{1}.jsp</result>
   <interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>
</action>
```